# Unable to download node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I was unable to download node-sass node module. I was getting following error.

Command to download node-sass module
**npm  install --save-dev node-sass**

**Error**
Binary has a problem: Error: \?\C:...\src\main\WebBundles\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-64\binding.node is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: See this https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2438 ?

Comment: Or try npm rm node-sass and then npm install node-sass

Answer (score 0):

Download required binding node from below git URL.
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases

1. Create a folder with name "sass-binary" under C:\Users\AppData\Roaming. and paste the downloaded file into above newly created folder.
2. Add C:\Users\AppData\Roaming to environmental variable PATH.
3. Add "SASS_BINARY_DIR=C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\sass-binary" .npmrc file

Now npm install - not a valid Win32 application issue should be resolved.